# How to apply a given width/margin in singularity.gs?

Tags: css, sass, 960.gs, singularitygs

I am using singularity.gs (Drupal 7/Omega 4), and I want to stack my content in columns.

In 960gs, you just add `grid-4` to the element, and it spans 4 columns with appropriate margins (more or less).

To make a 12-column grid with sigularity.gs I've written this:

```scss
.grid-4 {
    width: column-span(4, 6);
    margin-left: gutter-span();
    float: left;
}

.grid-4:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Is there a simpler or more idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a question per se, but I think I can answer it.

Singularity allows different [output styles](https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Output-Styles) to provide their own [span mixins](https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid) to better adhere to that output style's mental model. 960gs works on the float output style, allowing you to to change what you have to the following:

```scss
.grid-4 {
    @include float-span(4);

    &:nth-of-type(3n) {
        @include float-span(4, 'last');
    }
}
```

A working [SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4738ffa79a9198ec5798) with this should give you a clear idea of what's going on.

Comment: That is what I wanted.  Maybe there was no  question, but the answer was great :-)